# How to change $PATH variable in bash_profile in OSX?

Tags: macos, python-3.x, terminal

I am trying to install a 3rd party library from GitHub through terminal. Before this  installed Anaconda Python distribution on my system and that has modified my root directory of my terminal to;
          `Vinos-MBP:~ Vino$`

So when try to navigate to a particular directory to install the said library using 

`cd /Users/Vino/<install location>`

The terminal prints the following message;

`-bash: cd: /Users/Vino/Documents/My: No such file or directory`

I know this problem is because Python has modified my `bash_profile` startup file. I tried various online methods to fix this [issue](https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/add-shell-path-osx/), but nothing actually works. Whenever I restart my terminal and navigate using `cd`, I get the same error. How do I reset `$PATH` to `$HOME` (like as before installing Anaconda), so that I can navigate to any folder on my system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a problem with `$PATH` or `$HOME` -- it looks to me like you have a space in the folder name, and aren't properly quoting/escaping it. If they aren't quoted or escaped, spaces are taken as separators between arguments (e.g. folder paths) rather than part of the path. If the folder you're trying to `cd` to is "/Users/Vino/Documents/My Installation Location", you could use any of these:

```
cd "/Users/Vino/Documents/My Installation Location"
cd '/Users/Vino/Documents/My Installation Location'
cd /Users/Vino/Documents/My\ Installation\ Location
cd ~/Documents/My\ Installation\ Location
cd ~/"Documents/My Installation Location"  # Note that the ~/ part must not be quoted
```

There are a number of other characters that're perfectly legal to have in filenames that will cause trouble when used on the command line without quotes or escapes (including the quote and escape characters themselves!). One way to avoid trouble is to drag-and-drop an item from the Finder into the Terminal window, and it'll fill in a (properly escaped) path to that item.